# How to make Javascript function Dryer with two functions in a function

Tags: javascript

I got told the best way to learn Javascript is to play with it. But I'm certain I can make this dryer?

I've got two fixed divs side by side which scroll independently.( I want to display the scroll height in another fixed on top of each box when scrolled.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6aqbgqwy/

```
var leftBox = document.getElementById('left-box');

var rightBox = document.getElementById('right-box');

var leftBoxScrollTopContainer = document.getElementById('left-scroll-height');
var rightBoxScrollTopContainer = document.getElementById('right-scroll-height');

function showScrollTop() {
    leftBox.onscroll = function(){
        leftBoxScrollTopContainer.innerHTML = leftBox.scrollTop + "px"; 
    }
    rightBox.onscroll = function(){
        rightBoxScrollTopContainer.innerHTML = rightBox.scrollTop + "px";   
    }
};

showScrollTop();
```

Comment: When you say 'dryer', do you mean 'cleaner'?

Comment: @DanielDewhurst DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: He means Don't Repeat Yourself 'er

Comment: If it can be 'cleaner'. I'd love to know. But yes, I meant 'DRY' as in 'Don't Repeat Yourself'. Which is ultimately cleaner code anyway.

Comment: You may get a better response to this at [codereview.se], but please check that site's help pages to ensure your question is a good fit for that community.

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks I will check this community out.

Comment: Make sure you add some context.

Comment: What you have are components. Those can be simple objects or full-blown objects with prototype functions. You'll end up with *more* code, but it'll be re-usable and potentially easier to reason about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's not much point using a function as you're basically binding two functions on two separate events.

```
var leftBox = document.getElementById('left-box');
var rightBox = document.getElementById('right-box');
var leftBoxScrollTopContainer = document.getElementById('left-scroll-height');
var rightBoxScrollTopContainer = document.getElementById('right-scroll-height');

leftBox.onscroll = function() {
    leftBoxScrollTopContainer.innerHTML = leftBox.scrollTop + "px";
}

rightBox.onscroll = function() {
    rightBoxScrollTopContainer.innerHTML = rightBox.scrollTop + "px";
}
```

I can't really see a cleaner, or DRY'er way of doing this. Even with jQuery you're going to have the same amount of code near or less.

Comment: Or *more* code if you probably break everything out. But DRY doesn't mean less code.

Comment: After 3 years I finally came back and accepted this as there was no point using a function to call the onScroll events.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
function showScrollTop(prefix){
    var box = document.getElementById(prefix + '-box');
    var container = document.getElementById(prefix + '-scroll-height');

    box.onscroll = function(){
        container.innerHTML = box.scrollTop + "px"; 
    }
}

showScrollTop("left");
showScrollTop("right");
```

OR by passing prefixes as an `array`:

```
function showScrollTop(prefixes){
    for(var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++){
        (function(prefix){
            var box = document.getElementById(prefix + '-box');
            var container = document.getElementById(prefix + '-scroll-height');

            box.onscroll = function(){
                container.innerHTML = box.scrollTop + "px"; 
            }
        })(prefixes[i]);
    }
}

showScrollTop(["left", "right"]);
```

Comment: Top solution works perfectly. Thanks for that, didn't even think of using parameters. Everything I write ends up being so basic!